# Detecting a high-resistance fault location (like corrosion)

Tags: cables, fault

I recently encountered a problem where i had a 2 wire cable, one wire with corrosion somewhere and the other wire is perfectly fine. I didn't have a replacement so I wanted to try and find out where the corrosion was (it was giving around 1 megaohm resistance not completely cut.)

I connected it to the live terminal of a wall outlet and used my non contact voltage tester.

Silly me it kept beeping across the **whole length**.  I couldn't find the fault. J thought that the resistance might impede it and the signal would start to fade.

Anyhow, I eventually figured it out using my multimeter and kept bending small segments until I found an area where the resistance varied greatly and to my surprise it was the area of corrosion.

Is there any other "easy" way of finding out where the high resistance fault is without wasting much time? (I didn't have a cable toner so couldn't test with it.)

Comment: A time-domain reflectometer is easy but not cheap.

Comment: I had this problem once, but the cable was 1000 ft long and buried! You can cobble together a time-domain reflectometer with an oscilloscope and a pulse generator (which I built from a TTL hex inverter). Dug up a few feet and bingo, there it was.

Comment: damn, thank you so much vir and mark, but lol changing it is easier. also cheers mark for the almost DIY solution

Comment: Just another idea which may be worth exploring, use the wire that you want to test as the antenna of the pitch oscillator of a [Theremin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin).. perhaps there is a sudden "jump" in frequency, at the same separation, which gets generated due to the non-uniform impedance distribution of the antenna (i.e. broken wire). Search online for "theremin circuit" there are plenty..  This may prove especially interesting for short wires where time domain reflectometry becomes difficult as you need really short and steep pulses

Comment: @PauComaRamirez you know what, i will build it specially to verify this and come back with a youtube video and results. if that works you've just earned rep for that awesome idea

Comment: Great ! I'll be very interested to see what happens, Do post a link to the video. =)